Ubuntu studio upgrade failed halfway through
I am trying to upgrade to the newest ubuntu studio - everything seemed to be working fine but it failed halfway through. I wasnt paying the closest attention so I cant tell you what  it said exactly. I think it said it failed fetching something. It resulted in a softlock - I could move the mouse and click some things but everything was non responsive. I had to reboot, only now it wont boot at all. I've got "press enter for maintenance or control-D to continue. pressing control D says "default.target is not inactive. Please review the default.target setting. Fallback to the single-user shell"
Can someone help? I did a cursory search but found nothing recent or related.

Reinstall a fresh copy of the version of Studio, which by the way you never said what version. After restore files from backup.
